# SQL Query Search fetch from same table filtering by status

Tags: mysql, asp.net, sql, sql-server

Allright...the Query is,
I have a Table: `Website_Articles` 
The Columns `Article, Id, Author, PublishedOn, ArticleName` are common slots used for storing data for different pages. it is differentiated by giving a Status ID. (eg: attahced pic)

[image]

What i want to achieve is on using the search query, i want to filter the result data only from a specific column by the status ID mentioned or the search result should not come from the status ID mentioned. (both ways is ok) 
the command i have right is this....

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Article, 0, CHARINDEX(' ', Article, 300)) + '...' 
AS Article, Id, Author, PublishedOn, ArticleName 
FROM Website_Articles 
WHERE (Article LIKE '%' + @Article + '%') or 
(ArticleName LIKE '%' + @ArticleName + '%' )
```

but this brings out everything from `Website_Articles`

Any assistance would be much appreciated.
thank you.

Comment: Is you question about mysql or sql-server?

Comment: read this a few times, still can't work out exactly what you're asking. Is it that one article can have multiple rows with different statuses and you only want to return one row if the filter is met across any of the rows?

Comment: Thanks but @BWS answer got me going in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could this be what you are looking for??

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Article, 0, CHARINDEX(' ', Article, 300)) + '...' 
AS Article, Id, Author, PublishedOn, ArticleName 
FROM Website_Articles 
WHERE Status = 'Menu' AND
  ((Article LIKE '%' + @Article + '%') or 
   (ArticleName LIKE '%' + @ArticleName + '%' ))
```

or

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Article, 0, CHARINDEX(' ', Article, 300)) + '...' 
AS Article, Id, Author, PublishedOn, ArticleName 
FROM Website_Articles 
WHERE Status <> 'Menu' AND
  ((Article LIKE '%' + @Article + '%') or 
   (ArticleName LIKE '%' + @ArticleName + '%' ))
```

Comment: yes...exactly what i was looking for. thank you.
how to i go about if i wana add another status ID to be left out along with WHERE Status <> 'Menu'

Comment: could simply add like this:  WHERE Status <> 'Menu' AND Status <> 'somethingelse' AND

Comment: would you also help me out on this.
Suppose I want to pull Data from more than one Column using status on a gridview. what should i add to this?
**SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Website_Articles] where Status='Menu' ORDER BY [Id] DESC**
This is not for a Search result....check out this fiddle for the grid table: http://jsfiddle.net/Pr7UG/1/

Comment: you should post as a new question ... i've got a busy day ahead of me, and wont be spending too much time on this site today...

Comment: Ok..i will do that. Thank you agn